# First child of multiple selectors using CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to use `first-child` on the result of concatenating multiple css selectors.

Example: how to select `first-child` of the result of the css selectors `body .foo, body .bar`? In words: select all elements that has class foo that exists in the body element AND select all elements that has class bar that exists in the body element. Now take the first element in the collection of returned elements.

Comment: `body > p:first-child`?

Comment: My question was how to use `first-child` on `body .foo, body .bar`. Your answer says "first p-element in the body-element. My question is how to select "first element that has the class foo or bar in the body element".

Comment: "I want to use first-child on the result of concatenating multiple css selectors." No, you don't. Since the elements aren't related in any way other than simply appearing anywhere within the body element, you don't want to use :first-child. It is not possible to write a selector for this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body > p:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <p class="foo">Hello</p>
   <p class="bar">Hello</p>
   <p class="foo">Hello</p>
   <p class="bar">Hello</p>
</body>
```

Comment: A small description like `why this helps or what you are doing here` does not hurt any one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/307/)**

For the first `.foo`

```
body p:nth-child(1){...}
```

For the first `.bar`

```
body p:nth-child(2){...}
```

First of all `<p>`

body > p:first-child{...}